# Route phone audio call to a custom sound service in android?

Tags: java, android, c++, audio, audioflinger

I have implemented my custom audio interface which is derived from AudioHardwareBase, and I have initialized it in AudioFlinger constructor class. This class will stream the audio through network.
This work fine when I play sound from a file, but not when make phone call.
The problem is due probably because the audio of phone call come from hardware unlike audio file (which come from software).
I'm willing to modify basic android library/driver in order to get this work.
Any idea how can I overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Android does not handle transport of voice call audio - it's managed by the platform. Android tells the platform (through the Audio HAL) how to route the voice audio, but neither the Audio HAL nor any other part of Android ever sees the actual audio data, except when you do voice call recording. The solution to your problem (and whether it can be solved at all) depends highly on which platform you're targeting. And without having the full source code you might not be able to get far.

Comment: I'm working on the Motorola Atrix 4G. I guess I need custom Motorola c++ classes which It's impossible to get. I have aborted this approach.